# Update appwidgets at exact time with repeating (AlarmManager with setExactAndAllowWhileIdle method)

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have a project with 2 types of appwidgets each of which has own AppWidgetProvider.
All widgets show current date, therefore have to be updated every midnight at exact time.

I've tested the situation when there are two appwidgets on Home Screen: one instance of each widget type.

On my Nokia with Android 10 everthing works fine: both of widgets are updated at every midnight stable. Action is repeated.

But on my OnePlus with Android 12 based on Oxygen OS I observe very strange behaviour: at the first midnight after putting widget on the home screen both of widgets were updated (date of the day was actual), but at the second midnight only one of the widgets was updated, and the second one stopped updating.

Important note: before tests on OnePlus I canceled battery optimization from OnePlus for the app - to avoid stopping process.

My code is below...

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
// Android 12 requires for exact methods of AlarmManager
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Every receiver for every type of appwidgets includes

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_TODAY" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**In every AppWidgetProviderInfo (xml files) for each widget type i have a string**

```
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
```

**AppWidgetProvider for the first widget**

```
class WidgetPeriodProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

private var APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"

// For AlarmManager
private val ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_PERIOD = "ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_PERIOD"

override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {
    ...

    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
        updateWidgetPeriod(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
    }
    
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
}

override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {

    // Set Auto Update with AlarmManager
    setAlarmManagerPeriod(context)

    super.onEnabled(context)
}

override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {

    // Disable Auto Update with AlarmManager
    disableAlarmManagerPeriod(context)

    super.onDisabled(context)
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    if (
        intent.action.equals(AlarmManager.ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_PERIOD) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
        intent.action.equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)
    ) {
        val thisAppWidget = ComponentName(
            context.packageName, javaClass.name
        )
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(context)
        val ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget)
        // Update widgets
        for (appWidgetId in ids) {
            updateWidgetPeriod(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
        // AlarmManager Auto Update Reschedule
        setAlarmManagerPeriod(context)
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent)
}
```

**AppWidgetProvider for the second widget**

```
class WidgetTodayProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

private var APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"

// For AlarmManager
private val ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_TODAY = "ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_TODAY"

override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {
    ...

    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
        updateWidgetToday(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
    }
    
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
}

override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {

    // Set Auto Update with AlarmManager
    setAlarmManagerToday(context)

    super.onEnabled(context)
}

override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {

    // Disable Auto Update with AlarmManager
    disableAlarmManagerToday(context)

    super.onDisabled(context)
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    if (
        intent.action.equals(AlarmManager.ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_TODAY) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
        intent.action.equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE) ||
        intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)
    ) {
        val thisAppWidget = ComponentName(
            context.packageName, javaClass.name
        )
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(context)
        val ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget)
        // Update widgets
        for (appWidgetId in ids) {
            updateWidgetToday(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
        // AlarmManager Auto Update Reschedule
        setAlarmManagerToday(context)
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent)
}
```

**Function for setting alarm - the first widget type**

```
private fun setAlarmManagerPeriod(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, WidgetPeriodProvider::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_PERIOD
    val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 0
    c[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
    c[Calendar.SECOND] = 3

    val alarmManager = context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    // For Android 12 and higher check permission for AlarmManager at exact time
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val hasPermission: Boolean = alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()
        if(hasPermission) {
            // Permission granted - use exact method
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.timeInMillis,
                pIntent
            )
        } else {
            // Permission is not granted - use inexact method
            alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.timeInMillis,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pIntent
            )
        }
    } else {
        // For Android below 12 use exact method
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            c.timeInMillis,
            pIntent
        )
    }
}
```

**Function to disable alarm - the first widget type**

```
private fun disableAlarmManagerPeriod(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, WidgetPeriodProvider::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_PERIOD
    val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    val alarmManager = context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.cancel(pIntent)
}
```

**Function for setting alarm - the second widget type**

```
private fun setAlarmManagerToday(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, WidgetTodayProvider::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_TODAY
    val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 0
    c[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
    c[Calendar.SECOND] = 1

    val alarmManager = context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    // For Android 12 and higher check permission for AlarmManager at exact time
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val hasPermission: Boolean = alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()
        if(hasPermission) {
            // Permission granted - use exact method
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.timeInMillis,
                pIntent
            )
        } else {
            // Permission is not granted - use inexact method
            alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.timeInMillis,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pIntent
            )
        }
    } else {
        // For Android below 12 use exact method
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            c.timeInMillis,
            pIntent
        )
    }
}
```

**Function to disable alarm - the first widget type**

```
private fun disableAlarmManagerToday(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, WidgetTodayProvider::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_TODAY
    val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    val alarmManager = context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.cancel(pIntent)
}
```

**Could you help me, please, to answer the question? - Why not all the widgets are updated at every midnight? What's wrong with my code?**

Comment: you won't be able to use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` from [Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exact-alarm-permission). Try using `WorkManager` but running exactly at midnight can not be guaranteed.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Thank you for your comment, I need appwidget updating at exact time, because the current date in widgets should be updated at midnight. Unfortunatly, WorkManaget doesn't allow updating at exact time. I've looked through a lot of articles, videos, discussions here, but I don't understand what modern and working tools Google gives for actions at exact time. After getting Android 12 on OnePlus I observe that even Google Calendar app can have delay 1-2 minutes in events notification sometimes. What time delay in updates can be in case of WorkManager?

Comment: You might find it easier to set up a broadcast receiver to listen for ACTION_DATE_CHANGED. 
Note, You don't have to worry about your process being stopped, as the alarms will go off even if the app is not running.